# CGI programming in C

Tags: c, cgi, forms

I have a general question about CGI programming in C.

I use an embedded web server to handle web interface. For this purpose I have a HTML file stored in the server. In this HTML file there is JavaScript and CSS code. So far so good.

When user presses the "Submit" button, I receive the form data in my CGI program. But I can't understand how to return the same data back to user's form. Do I need to read HTML file, copy it to a buffer, parse data, fill in forms with user's data, and send the buffer (not HTML file) back to the browser (using for example `puts` function)?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It's a bit difficult figuring out what you want to do. Why do you want your server to send back the same data to the HTML form? Are you trying to do a partial page update? (AJAX?) Have you worked through some basic tutorials about CGI programming, i.e. do you know how, and in what form, a CGI program is supposed to generate its output?

Answer (score 2):

You need to send exactly what you want the client browser to display.

That means a complete HTML page, with all the data you want where you want it. The way you describe it would work, but parsing HTML correctly is not trivial.

You should investigate using some form of templating system like [libctemplate](http://libctemplate.sourceforge.net/doc.html) (I have no experience with this, but you'll find others by searching).

Or using AJAX to do the POST and return back only XML or JSON, letting the frontend JavaScript  deal with updating the page.

Comment: As far as I understand  AJAX script works on the client site.But some kind of templating library should do the trick.

Comment: Yes, AJAX is client side. The client part could do an AJAX request instead of the plain form POST, and your CGI could return JSON, XML or plain text that the client side code could use for updating the display.